# Embed @font-face fonts when Printing to PDF with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, font-face

I have a page that I'm rendering only in Chrome with a bunch of custom fonts:

```
@font-face{ font-family: BodyFont; src: url('fonts/font.ttf'); }
```

The browser renders everything perfectly. However, when I try to print this to PDF, there are two issues:

1. Chrome's Print-Preview sometimes does not display text in some fonts, or mangles it. This view is passed on to whatever printing device I use. Closing/re-opening the tab does not change the preview. However, restarting the browser does.
2. No matter what I do, I can't produce a PDF with the fonts embedded. I have tried Chrome's "Save to PDF", which produces a PDF that Adobe Acrobat cannot open. A variety of PDF Printers (such as Adobe's) do not produce PDFs with these fonts embedded, even though replacing the `@font-face`s with standard web fonts does produce embedded fonts.

Any help with either issue is appreciated.

Comment: For anyone searching, it appears that this has been fixed in later Chromium verisons. Using Chromium 69, a font-face with a TTF src properly gets embedded in the resulting PDF.

Answer (score 3):

Comment out media query in CSS or HTML, re-open browser and it would load the web font in print-preview, then, re-add media query section, and it works.

I found this workaround from here：[@font-face embedded fonts do not show up in a print preview](https://getsatisfaction.com/fontdeck/topics/_font_face_embedded_fonts_do_not_show_up_in_a_print_preview)

Comment: I found a capture of it on the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20150616043424/https://getsatisfaction.com/fontdeck/topics/_font_face_embedded_fonts_do_not_show_up_in_a_print_preview

Answer (score -2):

Try to load default font while printing. Add the below lines to your css and try.

```
@media print {
 body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;       
  }
}
```